# Why use conio.h?

Tags: c++, c, input, console, conio

I often see people use the header file of `conio.h` in C and C++, although  I can´t see any major benefits in use of the functions inside of `conio.h` in comparison to the standard library functions. `conio.h` has furthermore the disadvantages of being dependent on the Windows/MS-DOS environment and not being part of the C standard.

- What is the reason to choose functions of `conio.h`?
- What do functions inside of `conio.h` provide, what the functions of the standard C libraries can't?
- Why to choose the `conio` library?

Comment: `conio` means console I/O. So it is for console applications.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie Don´t the standard libries provide input/output operations for console applications, too?

Comment: It has an easy way to get raw keyboard input

Comment: Code can determine if data is in `stdin` _now_.  Std C has no concept of time within `stdin`.  `stdin` is just a sequence of bytes.

Comment: There's no equivalent to, for example, `kbhit` in the standard C library.

Comment: It never fails to amaze me how many people still use Turbo C++.

Comment: See the documentations? There are functions like `kbhit` in the standard library.

Comment: @Ayxan -- which functions in the [C Standard Library](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7) are like `kbhit()`?

Comment: @exnihilo I meant to say there are functions like `kbhit` that does what standard library can't. I just messed up the comment being sleepy, Sorry!

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The conio.h header is specific to Turbo C, which predates the earliest C standard by several years.  It contains routines that are specific to the DOS command line.  One function here that's frequently used is `getch`, which allows reading one character at a time without having to press the Enter key.  It also contains `gotoxy` which allows placing the cursor at a specific location in the terminal

Generally speaking, methods of communicating with the terminal like this are very OS specific, so each has their own (typically non-portable) way of doing it.

This contrasts with the functions in stdio.h which contain functions like `printf`, `scanf`, and `getchar` which work regardless of what type of console is in use.

Comment: `<conio.h>` is supported by [MSVC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/console-and-port-i-o?view=vs-2019).  The names of the declared functions have been updated in more recent versions to follow the Standard C rules for implementation-specific names by adding a leading underscore (e.g. `_getch`).

Answer (score 4):

> What is the reason to choose functions of conio.h?

It has functions that are not provided by the standard library, and people who choose it don't (know to) care about porting to other systems.

> What do functions inside of conio.h provide, what the functions of the standard C libraries can´t?

These are some functions that don't have standard alternative. There may be others:

```
kbhit
clrscr
getch
getche
```

Standard library potentially *could* provide the functions. But it doesn't.

> Why to choose the conio library?

Because you've been taught to use it, and you don't (know to) care about porting to other systems.

Comment: A modern replacement might be `ncurses`.

Comment: @JesperJuhl Does ncurses support windows though? PDCurses is a curses port that supports windows.

Comment: Another replacement may be to use a windowing or graphics framework.

Comment: Qt can also replace some of the functionality some of the time while being cross-platform.