# leap year and long/shot months at next day date program

Tags: c, date

there is an easy way that includes all of the "days" conditions that can be in the year? leap year, long/shot months, etc...
trying to make it shorter but easy to understand for someone new at code like me

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct date
{
    int day;
    int month;
    int year;
} date;

int main()
{
    date d;
    printf("\nPlease enter the date DD/MM/YYYY format and i will raise it up \n");
    scanf_s("%d/%d/%d", &d.day, &d.month, &d.year);
    printf("you enter: %02d/%02d/%04d", d.day, d.month, d.year);
    d.day++;
    if (d.day == 29 && d.month == 2)
    {
        d.month++;
        d.day = 1;
    }
    if (d.day == 32 && d.month == 3)
    {
        d.month++;
        d.day = 1;
    }
    if (d.day == 32 && d.month == 12)
    {
        d.year++;
        d.month = 1;
        d.day = 1;
    }
    printf("  tomorrow date: %02d/%02d/%04d", d.day, d.month, d.year);
}
```

Comment: `if (d.day == 32 && d.month == 12)` ?

Comment: Why you dont' make condition of leap year ?

Comment: You don't seem to validate that the date the user entered is plausible.  You don't check that `scanf_s()` worked.  Given a valid month and a day, you can check whether the current day is the last day of the month, and if it is, cycle to the first of the next month, remembering to change the year too.  At the moment, your code only handles March correctly; December has been resolved; but you still need to sort out the other months, remembering to handle leap years for February.

Comment: Anyway stop using Turbo C. It's obsolete. You should conform to the C standards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your original question: "What am I doing wrong?"

```
if (d.day == 29 && d.month == 2)
```

Should be

```
if (d.day == 28 && d.month == 2)
```

And in the same way `32` should be `31`

To answer the question that you posted as an answer: "there is an easy way that includes all of the "days" conditions that can be in the year?"

```
const int dInM[12] = {31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31};

if( d.day == dInM[d.month-1] ) {
    
    ++d.month;
    d.day = 1;
}
```

Comment: and you use a this condition for leap year   ;  ((d.year%400==0)||(d.year%4==0&&d.year%100!=0))

Comment: The line `d.day++;` makes the first part of your answer incorrect. And the 2nd part does not increase the year in December.

Comment: I don't have any `d.day++` in the answer and yes it doesn't account for the year stuff. It was meant to be an answer to his particular question, not a working program.

Comment: I think your comment was for MED LDN answer. Lol

Answer (score 1):

An easy way to include all conditions would be to use the standard library `<time.h>`. It defines a structure to hold the date, `struct tm` (so you don't need to create your own) and has many useful functions such as `mktime`, which adjusts the date taking care of everything (change of month, change of year, leap years etc).
Here is an example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(void)
{
    struct tm d;

    printf("Please enter the date DD/MM/YYYY format and I will raise it up\n");
    scanf_s("%d/%d/%d", &d.tm_mday, &d.tm_mon, &d.tm_year);
    d.tm_mon -= 1; // struct tm saves months from 0 to 11
    d.tm_year -= 1900; // struct tm requires years passed since 1900

    printf("You entered: %02d/%02d/%04d\n", d.tm_mday, d.tm_mon + 1, d.tm_year + 1900);

    d.tm_mday++;
    mktime(&d); // Make the necessary adjustments after having modified the day

    printf("Tomorrow date: %02d/%02d/%04d\n", d.tm_mday, d.tm_mon + 1, d.tm_year + 1900);
}
```

Here I used `printf` so I had to re-add the values I subtracted before, but `<time.h>` actually includes functions to easily print the date both in standard (`asctime`, `ctime`) and custom formats (`strftime`). There are many resources online (including SO!) to understand in depth everything it offers, have a look!

Sidenote: you don't use anything from `<stdlib.h>`, you should't include unnecessary libraries

Comment: Uhm, I don't, I code in VIM and compile with Clang, why?

Comment: I used to relate `conio.h` to Turbo C. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59812014/why-use-conio-h Anyways just use the standard stuff

Comment: Well, I didn't even know about that library before today, I just copied it from OP (as a matter of fact when I tested the code I used `scanf` instead of `scanf_s`)

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct date
{
    int day, month,year;
}date;

int main()
{
  date d;
  printf("\nPlease enter the date DD/MM/YYYY format and i will raise it up \n");
  scanf("%d%d%d",&d.day, &d.month,&d.year);
  printf("you enter: %02d/%02d/%04d", d.day, d.month, d.year); //Keep in mind that the %02d means two characters minimum width,The 0 means to pad the field using zeros and the 2 means that the field is two characters wide
  d.day++;

  switch(d.month)
  {
      case 1:
      case 3:
      case 5:
      case 7:
      case 8:
      case 10:
      case 12:
      {
           if(d.day>=32)
           {
                 d.month++;
                 d.day=d.day-31;
           }
      }break;
      case 4:
      case 6:
      case 9:
      case 11:
      {
           if(d.day>=31)
           {
                 d.month++;
                 d.day=d.day-30;
           }break;
      }
      case 2:
      {
             if ((d.year%400==0)||(d.year%4==0&&d.year%100!=0)&&d.day>=30)
             {
                   d.month++;
                   d.day=d.day-29;
             }
             else
             {
                   d.month++;
                   d.day=d.day-28;
             }
      }break;

  }

   printf("\ntomorrow date: %02d/%02d/%04d\n", d.day, d.month, d.year);
}
```

Comment: Here's @Jonny_Mopp comment to your answer: "The line d.day++; makes the first part of your answer incorrect. And the 2nd part does not increase the year in December. "