# Using _ungetch and std::getline together

Tags: c++

Is there any generic (non-os-specific) way in c++ to use ungetch()/_ungetch() (conio.h) together with std::getline()? Or any way to read entire line when ungetch()/_ungetch() is used?

Comment: `conio.h`?? Are you writing code for MS-DOS using Turbo C / Turbo C++ or a similar obsolete (and pre-standard) toolchain that's stuck in the '90s?

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59812014/why-use-conio-h

Comment: Hi @jesper-juhl yes, it's for old-fashioned MS DOS app.